# Prove that $(√5 - 1)/2$ is irrational.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, radicals, irrational-numbers

Please help me prove that $(√5 - 1)/2$ is irrational.
I know how to prove √5 is irrational:

> Assume that √5 is rational meaning

√5 = $p/q$ $p,q$  $are$ $Z$ $and$  $q≠0$

$p^2/q^2 = 5$

$q^2 = p^2/5$

> Therefore, 5 must be a factor of p.

$Let$ $p = 5c$

$q^2 = (5c)^2/5$

$q^2 = 25c^2/5$

$c^2 = q^2/5$

> Therefore, 5 must also be a factor of q. CONTRADICTION!

Thanks.

Comment: Can you prove that $\sqrt{5}$ is irrational?

Comment: Then how about assuming $\frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{2}$ were rational and deducing that $\sqrt{5}$ would be rational?

Comment: If $\frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{2}=\frac{m}{n}$ for some $m,n\in\mathbb Z^+$, then $\sqrt{5}=\frac{2m+n}{n}\in\mathbb Q$, contradiction (you've just said you know how to prove $\sqrt{5}$ is irrational).

Comment: then suppose $\frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{2}=\frac{a}{b}\in \mathbb{Q}$, then $\sqrt{5}=\frac{2a+b}{b}\in \mathbb{Q}$: contradiction

Answer (score 7):

Let $\phi=\frac{\sqrt5-1}2$. Then rearranging gives$$\sqrt5=2\phi+1$$ If $\phi$ is rational, what does the above equality say about $\sqrt5$?

Answer (score 2):

Try This : (If you know how to prove $\sqrt{5}$ is irrational)

Suppose that $\frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{2}$ is rational.

Then there are $m ,n\neq0 \in \mathbb Z $ such that

$$\frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{2}=\frac{m-n}{2n}$$

Thus we get that $\sqrt{5}=\frac{m}{n}$.

Now proceed the way that you used to prove that $\sqrt{5} $ is irrational.